# Exception when getting a list of buckets on s3 using Jets3t

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using the S3 service i am trying to retrieve the list off all the buckets.While i am doing this i am getting an exception.

I am getting a S3 service exception: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer.

Here is the code:

```
    String awsKey = "awskey";
    String awsSecret = "secret";
    AWSCredentials aws = new AWSCredentials(awsKey,awsSecret);

    //communicate with s3
    try{
    S3Service service = new RestS3Service(aws);

    //get buckets
    S3Bucket[] buckets = service.listAllBuckets();
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
<code>    org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: Request Error:             java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
at org.jets3t.service.S3Service.listAllBuckets(S3Service.java:1370)
at UploadToS3.main(UploadToS3.java:20) Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
at org.apache.http.params.AbstractHttpParams.getIntParameter(AbstractHttpParams.java:70)
at org.apache.http.client.params.HttpClientParamConfig.getRequestConfig(HttpClientParamConfig.java:54)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:806)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRequest(RestStorageService.java:334)
at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRequest(RestStorageService.java:281)
at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRestGet(RestStorageService.java:981)
at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.listAllBucketsImpl(RestStorageService.java:1373)
at org.jets3t.service.StorageService.listAllBucketsImpl(StorageService.java:1379)
at org.jets3t.service.StorageService.listAllBuckets(StorageService.java:563)
at org.jets3t.service.S3Service.listAllBuckets(S3Service.java:1367)
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was an issue with http client , had to use an older version.

Was using 4.3.1 , had to use 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed, but not released ([HTTPCLIENT-1418](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1418)).
Look for the fix in version 4.3.2 of Apache HttpComponents HttpClient.